# Pronunciation of "Бог"

Tags: произношение

Does the word `Бог` (Nom. Sg.) end in a sound like `г` or `х`?

Comment: See [wiktionary](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B3#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B8.D0.B7.D0.BD.D0.BE.D1.88.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5). In English see [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B3#Pronunciation_3).

Comment: I pronounce Бог. But you can pronounce Бох if x is said shortly

Comment: U can talk as u want really: **Бог** or **Бох**, we talk both variants... It depends from personal pronounce more.

Comment: See answers to the recent question https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/14448/why-is-the-letter-%d0%b3-in-some-of-the-russian-words-pronounced-differently-as-it

Answer (score 3):

It depends. In the nominative case it's definitely бо**х**. The consonant -г- is pronounced close to Ukrainian -**хг**- in set expressions like "*Слава богу!*" (Dative) or "*Ступай с богом!*" (Instrumental), "*Проси у бога милости*" (Genitive), where бог is in *Christian* sense; however it is often reduced to the simple -**г**-. It's usually typical -**г**- in plural (бо**г**и, бо**г**ами, бо**г**ам, бо**г**ов...) or if it's about a **pagan** god (бо**г**а, бо**г**у, бо**г**ом, о бо**г**е - except the Nominative case - still бо**х**).

Answer (score 2):

The spelling "г" is due to old pronunciation. But in modern Russian, we usually say "Бох" due to Church Slavonic (although in Church Slavonic spelling the word still ends in "гъ"). Also sometimes people say "Бок", but this is thought to be an error.

Comment: *So in a Church service they say "Бог"* - 1. With *they*, do you mean the "priest", the "clergy" or everyone participating? 2. With *in a Church service*, do you mean during the event when people gather in the so called church building, *they* (see 1.) switch generally to `[бог]` or only when reading texts or only when reading from the scriptures itself?

Comment: Actually, Russian recension of Church Slavonic requires pronouncing *г* as a fricative, so *бог* is (or at least should be) rendered *[box]* in the church service. This has influenced fricative *г* in this only word in Moscow dialect of Russian, which renders *г* as a stop (*[g]* or *[k]*) elsewhere, except for adjectives in m. sg. gen.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really a christian so I made a foolish mistake. It's just other way round. The spelling is due to Old Russian pronounce "г". But in modern Russian the Church Slavonian variant "х" has prevailed. I rewrite the answer.

Comment: If someone is referring to non-Christian deity or Christian one outside of idioms, then u cannot pronounce it with a fricative.

Comment: @Anixx Why not? Such a habit.

Answer (score 1):

It is neither г nor x. It is something between г and x, like г in Belarusian or in Ukrainian. Yes, this sound doesn't exist in Russian as a single letter, but it may appear in some words.

Comment: Does such a sound appear in any other words beside Бог?

Answer (score -5):

The pronunciation is [бог] in standard Russian, in general context (outside of idioms). This follows the general Russian rules of devoicing at the end in certain circumstances so it can become [бок] before voiceless consonants.